# why cpulimit makes process STOPPED?

Tags: python, linux, process, operating-system, cpu-usage

I'm running a python script which uses networkx package to run some algorithms on graphs.
It takes a long time and has high cpu usage (99%), so I want to limit its cpu usage.

I used cpulimit on this process to limit the cpu usage to 60%

```
cpulimit -p 29780 -l 60
```

however, when I use it, the process got STOPPED, as below

```
[lily@geland academic]$ python run.py
the number of nodes in the graph is: 16264

[1]+  Stopped                 python run.py
```

but the cpu usage is still 60%

what is wrong and how to deal with such situations?
thanks!

Comment: threads? forked copies? You only limited one pid...

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand

Comment: when and how did you call `cpulimit`?